# Java : Pass data from href to a div modal panel

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl

I'm working on my jsp and I try to pass a parameter to a div, I put the parameter in the href:

```
href="#modal1?name=<c:out value="${module.name}"/>"
```

but I don't know how to get it in the div #module1 :

```
      <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${modules}" var="module">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${module.name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${module.type}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${module.atk}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${module.def}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${module.pulse}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${module.timer}"/></td>
            <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger padd-reduit" href="#modal1?name=<c:out value="${module.name}"/>"><i class="mdi-action-shopping-cart left small"> <c:out value="${module.token}"/> token</i></a></td>                  
            <div id="modal1" class="modal">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <h4>Voulez vous vraiment acheter ce module ?</h4>
                <p></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Oui</a>
                <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Non</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: Which `href`? Which `div`?

Comment: @LutzHorn href="#modal1?name=<c:out value="${module.name}"/>" to the module1 div

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include this information there.

Comment: @LutzHorn I did it :)

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely not the way to do it :)

If you only want the name then in your href it should be something like:

```
<a href="?name=${module.name}#modal1">myLink</a>
```

And in your modal div you should have something like:

```
<c:out value="${param['name']}">
```

where 'name' is the name of the query parameter.

Comment: Buthow to rename <div id="modal1" class="modal"> ? Because if i click on the href, it can't refer to this div because of the parameter

Comment: I didn't test this, but actually, it should be: <a href="?name=${module.name}#modal1">myLink</a> Since the hash part should be at the end.

Comment: I don't work, i tryed this: href="#modal1?name=${module.name}" with <div id="modal1?name=${module.name}" class="modal"> But still doesn't work :(

Comment: Your missing the point :) The div should stay the same, meaning: <div id="modal1" class="modal"> and the link should be <a href="?name=${module.name}#modal1">myLink</a>. The point is, the #modal1 calls the modal1 div (I assume there's more to it but I'm simplifying), and the ?name=${module.name} tells that a request parameter with the name 'name' and value ${module.name} should be sent as well. Now, the #modal1 is the hash part of the url and should always be last. Long story short, the div was correct from the beginning, :) Add to it only the <c:out value="${param['name']}"> so you print it.